# create dump file from database in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=sysadmin --no-data test > "C:\test1\ttt.dump";
```

This the command that i fire to create dump from mysql database , that's working fine and create dump with no data.

but I want some table with data , this command create dump with table that all are blank.

Comment: Removing the `no-data` switch would be a wild guess of mine.

Comment: @Bobby: How about making that an answer so you can collect points for it?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: I was not sure if it is an answer. The description of the flag is a little vague.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the `no-data` switch would be a wild guess of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can create dump of whole db using this command

```
     mysqldump -uUserName -pPassword --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --hex-blob SchemaName > FileName.sql
```

Just enter proper UserName,Password SchemaName and filename.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do it with 1 command, but theres a way to get creative.

1. Dump the database without data
2. Dump only the tables you want with data

Now you have 2 options:

- Open the second dumpfile in editor and use find/replace option to replace `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` or
- When importing the second file with data use a `--force` option when importing the dump file